# Retrieve data from firebase Web and display (also save) to firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working web application that is saving data to firebase web and generates a QR code of the (pushed) KEY of saved data. 
My android application is having a QR scanner which scans the QR and gets the KEY as a string. How to display as well as save all the data to firebase android after users scans that QR.

My data looks like this
[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jaCI.png) , where items inside zitems is not fixed it can be more than one

A small portion of my Qr scan Activity where I initialized firebase of my web app

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("docket-web-app")
            .setApiKey("api key")
            .setDatabaseUrl("database URL")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "secondary");
```

This method is called when scan is completed

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String scanResult = result.getText();

    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(qrScanActivity.this, DataSaveActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", scanResult);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
builder.setMessage("Do want to save this receipt to your account");
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Now I pass the key as string to DataSaveActivity which looks like

```
public class DataSaveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String keyValue;
private RecyclerView mReceipt;
private DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent == null) {
        keyValue = null;
    } else {
        //keyValue = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
        keyValue = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    }

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("docket-web-app")
            .setApiKey("API KEY OF WEB APP")
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://docket-web-app.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "secondary");
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("secondary");
    mRef = database.getReference().child("Bills").child(keyValue);
    mRef.keepSynced(true);
    mReceipt = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.othersRecycler);
    mReceipt.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mReceipt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
//BELOW THIS :recycler viewcode code to fetch data from database
```

Now, When I am running the app it scans the QR and as soon as I click SAVE. It stopped working with error

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solution.engineering.docket_ereceipt/com.solution.engineering.docket_ereceipt.DataSaveActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database url specified**

I checked the URL its fine. 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Can you please show the URL since that's your error?

Comment: its already there, at datasaveActivity

Comment: @RishiRaj what is the url at `Qr scan Activity`?

Comment: It scans qr code and returns the key which is generated by web -app.

Comment: i used this [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) as a reference to access databases from two different projects